# Surjective morphism to Quotient sheaf, nonsurjective on sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $X=\mathbb{P}^1$ the projective line. Let $P=(1:0)$ and $Q=(0:1)$ be points on $X$, and $\mathscr{F}$ be the sheaf of regular functions on $X$. Define a subsheaf $\mathscr{F}'$ of $\mathscr{F}$ by
$$\mathscr{F}'(U) = \left\{ \begin{align}
&\{f \in \mathscr{F}(U); f(P)=f(Q)=0\}, &\text{if } P,Q \in U \\
&\{f \in \mathscr{F}(U); f(P)=0\}, & \text{if } P\in U, Q\notin U \\
&\{f \in \mathscr{F}(U); f(Q)=0\}, & \text{if } Q\in U, P\notin U \\
&\mathscr{F}(U), &\text{if } Q\notin U \text{and } P\notin U
\end{align} \right.$$ 
where $U$ is any open set in $X$. Define $\mathscr{F}'' = \mathscr{F}/\mathscr{F}'$.

The point here is that $$0\longrightarrow \mathscr{F}' \longrightarrow \mathscr{F} \longrightarrow \mathscr{F}'' \longrightarrow 0$$
gives a short exact sequence, but the natural map 
$$ \mathscr{F}(X) \longrightarrow \mathscr{F}''(X)$$ is (supposedly) not surjective.

Note that $\mathscr{F}(X) = k,$ and $\mathscr{F}'(X) = \{0\}$. Still, I fail to describe the global sections of $\mathscr{F}''$; can somebody help out?

Comment: The global section $\mathcal{F}''(X)$ of the quotient sheaf is $k^2$.

Comment: I heard so before, but why?

Comment: Two sections on $\mathcal{F}(U)$ are identified if their difference is contained in $\mathcal{F}'(U)$. Just looking at a few cases we see that the sections on $U$ containing neither $P,Q$ are zero. On $U$ containing only $P$ the sections are identified by their values at $P$, so the sections $\mathcal{F}''(U) = k$.

Comment: @Hoot I was only asking about the non-surjective part.

Comment: I see. I misread, then.

Comment: @basket I see what you are saying. If $U$ contains both $P$ and $Q$, they are identified by their value at both points, which would give something isomorphic to $k\times k$. However, in the given example we also require $f \in \mathscr{F}(X) = k$ (not just any $U$). If $f \in k$, is not f constant and therefore if $f(P)=g(P),$ also $f(Q) = g(Q)$?

Comment: @basket what do you mean by "since global sections on a closed projective variety are constant"? Just that $\mathscr{F}(X) = k$?

Comment: @basket what I meant in my first comment was, that the situation $f(P) = g(P),$ but $f(Q) \neq g(Q)$, which leads to the second $k$, does not occur in the case of global sections. So since the value of $f$ is the same at both points ($f \in k$), it is really just identified by one value, hence $k$, not $k^2$. Do you understand my point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34141/discussion-between-basket-and-foaly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient sheaf $\mathcal{F}'' = \mathcal{F} / \mathcal{F}'$ is defined to be the sheafification of the presheaf where the sections are $\mathcal{F}(U)/ \mathcal{F}'(U)$. Since the global sections of closed projective variety are contant, the global sections on the quotient presheaf are just $k$. However, take $U = Y\setminus \{P\}$ and $f \in \mathcal{F}''(U)$ (as an element of the presheaf) to be the constant $f = a \in k$ and similarly $V = Y\setminus \{Q\}$ with $g \in \mathcal{F}''(V)$ the constant $b \in k $ $ ( a\neq b)$. These sections agree at their intersection (since $U \cap V = Y\setminus \{P,Q\}$ and $\mathcal{F}''(U\cap V) = 0)$ and thus can be glued together into a non-constant section on $Y$. In this way $F''(Y)$ (this time as the associated sheaf) $\cong k \times k$

Comment: lovely summary of our discussion